# Magento 2.3.2 getting error after manually deleted products from mysql

Tags: products, magento2.3.2, product-reindexing

I had deleted product using **"DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity`"** in Magento 2.3.2. I am getting stuck in reindexing about error

```
`catalogsearch_fulltext_scope2`' exists., query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope2` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `attribute_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Attribute_id' ,
  `data_index` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Data index' ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`entity_id`, `attribute_id`),
  FULLTEXT `FTI_FULLTEXT_DATA_INDEX` (`data_index`)
) COMMENT='catalogsearch_fulltext_scope2' ENGINE=innodb charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

Please help me to resolve issue

Comment: This is actually an error ? does the error message show anything else ?, because this sql command should actualy not throw an error but just skip the command because the table already exists...

Comment: This is error message while i am doing php bin/magento indexer:reindex